# solr accurate match through copyField and defaultOperator

Tags: solr

In the Solr schema.xml, configure the field & and copyField

```
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />  
<field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
<field name="all" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="all"/>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

And do dataimport which incude a document like this: title="sport",content="I like basket".
Now i set query string as:
all:sport basket
I intent to get this document through match title field to "sport" and match content field to "basket".
I mean when i use "all: sport basket", sorl will hit the the document from the source document:

```
<title>sport</title>
<content>I like basket</content>
```

But sorl copyField seems can't do this, can anyone help?

Comment: What is the analyzer of fieldType text_zh?

Comment: is the default search field all ?? or can you try q=all:sport\ basket

Comment: @Junaid text_zh is just equivalent to text

Comment: @Jayendra Yes, default Search Field is all

Comment: can you explain a bit better which query is working and which one is not working? it seems like "all: sport basket" so I donøt understand what you want to achieve more...